# Move old site to subdomain in cPanel

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, drupal, migration

I want to move our current website from `www.xyz.com` to `oldsite.xyz.com`, so that I can stick a "coming soon" page in it's place.

The old site runs on Drupal, which I know nothing about. Am I right in thinking that I need to do the following:

- log in to cPanel (which I've never used before)
- manually create a new folder called 'oldsite'
- move everything from 'www' folder to 'oldsite' folder
- put the new html file in 'www'
- add DNS entry for 'oldsite' subdomain

Should I do anything else?
Will internal links still work?
What are we supposed to do with the `public_html` folder?

Comment: On a side note, be aware that having the old site online can open you up to **duplicate content penalties** with Google. You may want to use your robots.txt file to block the directory. I would at least add a canonical tag to old pages to point to new pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will vary depending on the Cpanel License, if its not a WHM unlimited license then these are the steps you need to take:

1. Login to Cpanel
2. Click sub domains under category 'domains'
3. Add a sub domain oldsite with root of `/oldsite/`
4. Copy all `/public_html/` or `www` depending on how cpanel was setup to `oldsite`
5. If the domain already has the name servers set to that of the cpanel hosting then there's no additional steps, if you use the registrar name servers and manually point to @ records then you need to add the ARecord of oldsite to point to the Cpanel IP Address.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I will try this out in the morning.