# Migrate old WordPress site to a subdomain via cPanel

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, cpanel, migration

I'm a volunteer with non-profit helping with their website. I'm accustomed to working the frontend, but not the backend. We recently connected the website domain to a new site on Squarespace. Since the domain is now connected to a new site, we can't access the old WordPress site to grab some additional content, etc. Therefore, we want to move the old WP site to an existing sub-domain at the WordPress host.

**How can I do this via the cPanel at the WordPress host?**  (The hosting provider has said they can do it for a fee, but the non-profit would like me to have a go at it first.)

Comment: Related: [Move old site to subdomain in cPanel](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51390/move-old-site-to-subdomain-in-cpanel), but there will probably be some additional WordPress configuration steps.

Answer (score 2):

Make the subdomain `old.example.com` and point it to the same directory as the original site

Open a database editor such as phpMyAdmin and enter the database for the original site.

If there is more than one database and you aren't sure which one, you will find it defined in `wp-config.php`

Look for `define( 'DB_NAME', 'user_database' );` the database name is whatever is in the place of `user_database`.

Once in the database, open the `wp_options` table and you should see two records.  One for `siteurl` and one for `home`, they will both have `https://example.com`.  If you can't see them both, one may be on the next page of records.

Double click the field that has your domain name and it should become editable, change it to `https://old.example.com`  - click away and it auto-saves.  Do this for both records.

If double click doesn't work, click the edit icon, make the changes and save for each.

Comment: I should have added that this is assuming that DNS is still at the original host and you have not updated the nameservers to Squarespace.  If you have, let me know and I will add another answer

Comment: Thank you. For various reasons,  it will be a couple of weeks before I have access to the cPanel.  I'll follow-up with you then if needed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

I migrated my old HTML website to WordPress not so long back.

I made the mistake not creating a .htacess file with my old site IP address.

Ping your website and enter the IP address into a web browser. If your WordPress site loads using the IP address you're good to go. If it does not, you need to add a .htaccess file to the root of your site using cPanel.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question about moving WordPress to a subdomain.